# Change database file through a controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is a `database.php` in `config` folder

```
 $tnsname = '(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST =        
 192.168.0.59)(PORT = 3021))
 (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = xe)))';

$db['default'] = array(
     'dsn'  => '',
     'hostname' => $tnsname,
     'username' => 'user',
     'password' => '******',
     'database' => '',
     'dbdriver' => 'oci8',
     'dbprefix' => '',
     'pconnect' => FALSE,
     'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
     'cache_on' => FALSE,
     'cachedir' => '',
     'char_set' => 'utf8',
     'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
     'swap_pre' => '',
     'encrypt' => FALSE,
     'compress' => FALSE,
     'stricton' => FALSE,
     'failover' => array(),
     'save_queries' => TRUE
 );
```

How do i change the variable value `$tnsname` through a `controller` ?

When the user authenticates in the system and choose a code in the login, this code will indicate which value goes in that variable (`$tnsname`)

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Yes just above this array in database.php file in config folder create a php function which check if there is a file on a particular location and if not. Now make your database in a if condition.

"This file is a json,php,xml,text" any which contains your users db information like host,user,pass

So if there is a file on a particular location, then your code will read it and extract the data from that file and use it as a variable as you want. So if user is not authorized then the default database is active and if the user is authorized then ci will use the if condition and will connect to other user database.

Hope it helps

And yes The same thing, I have done it for a multi vendor project in Codeigniter, and it worked. But my file login was a little complex coz there were so many users so I just put that in session and used the session variable.

Comment: I thank you but i do not understand very well. Could you show me an example?